# removeFromSuperView is not working in iPad2 with iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, ios5

I have a little issue from `removeFromSuperView` as it's not at least working with iPad2 with iOS 5. I'm displaying a custom UIView alert before my table populates with data and once done, I'm removing it from the super view. with every other device it's working fine except in iPad2 (iOS5). Am I missing anything?

### .h

```
@private
    SaveUIDisplayViewController *wbsSummaryLoadView;
```

### .m

```
// Displaying

wbsSummaryLoadView = [[SaveUIDisplayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SaveUIDisplayViewController" bundle:nil];
[[wbsSummaryLoadView view] setFrame:[self view].bounds];
[wbsSummaryLoadView setupSavingViewWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Loading...", @"")];
[[self view] addSubview:wbsSummaryLoadView.view];

// Removing 

[wbsSummaryLoadView.view removeFromSuperview];
[wbsSummaryLoadView release];
wbsSummaryLoadView = nil;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a problem somewhere else? What have you tried to debug this - breakpoints, stepped through the code, checked for nil objects? It could be something else that is failing. Have you checked the SDK for changes between iOS4 and 5? If you are certain that `removeFromSuperview` (I assume your uppercase V is a typo?) is  not working, then you should file a report with Apple. But I suspect it could be something elsewhere. Perhaps if you posted some code someone might spot it?

Comment: @NickBull: I have done every possible ways as you have mentioned, even checked the changes with SDK. Okay perhaps I can add some code here and sorry about that typo mistake.

Comment: updated with code. And when it's working with iPad(iOS5 as well as earlier versions), iPad2(iOS5) has this problem, but working in earlier versions for iPad2.

Comment: Is all the code you posted in the same method, or is it in two different methods?

Comment: They are of course in two different methods.

Comment: If they are in different methods then wbsSummaryLoadview is out of scope in the second one. How are you declaring / defining it there?

Comment: @jrturton: wbsSummaryLoadview is a private ivar, just to show it here, I have declared it as local.

Comment: I also face this issue now. One of my app feature is not working in app store due to this. Any idea? Did you solve this?

Comment: There is absolutely no way that there's an issue with UIView removeFromSuperview. However your viewController code is bad and should use UIViewController containment methods.

Comment: I'd like to see more code. For example, where it's added and where it's removed.

Comment: @Jessedc I had fixed it long back. However I just cant recall it right now, but there was an issue with removeFromSuperview.

Comment: I'm down voting this question because it's no longer a problem for you, therefore there's no answer (unless you provide one) and given you can't provide more specifics it's vague.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add a view you can release it right away. (a copy is creating by using addSubview)
Try:

```
[[self view] addSubview:wbsSummaryLoadView.view];
[wbsSummaryLoadView release];
```

and then you don't need to care, because if you release whole view you release that added view as well.

Comment: Unless you want to control wbsSummaryLoadView again somewhere else in the code and you've declared it as a member variable

Answer (score 0):

You are storing two different objects.  When you create the SaveUIDisplayViewController, you are declaring a new instance in that method.  When you are removing it, you are using (I guess) the member variable.

`SaveUIDisplayViewController *wbsSummaryLoadView = [[SaveUIDisplayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SaveUIDisplayViewController" bundle:nil];`

This will hide any declaration of wbsSummaryLoadView that you have defined in the header of the object.

And when you come to remove it

`[wbsSummaryLoadView.view removeFromSuperview];`

Has to have wbsSummaryLoadView declared somewhere so (this is where I'm guessing as you haven't posted your .h file) if this is declared in the header, then it won't be the same as the one when you created it (in fact it will probably be `nil` at this point)

Comment: Nick: No it's a single iVar(Private). Just for showing here, I have created a local var of SaveUIDisplayViewController.

Comment: I have declared wbsSummaryLoadView as private ivar in header file. please don't get confuse with the local var, it was only to show what kind if var it is. Hope I'm clear to you.

Comment: Ok.  I didn't see you comment that until after I'd posted the answer... Have you checked that `wbsSummaryLoadView.view` is not `nil` at the point where you call `removeFromSuperview` ?

Comment: yeah I have checked it twice. Everything is fine till that point.